# Parenthesis on echo shell command

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I have this echo command:

`$ echo "alias notepad++="C:/Program\ Files\ "(x86)"/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe"" >> ~/.bashrc`

[image]

As shown in the picture it does not recognize the parenthesis.

Comment: Since you have no variables in that line, you could also use single quotes: `echo 'alias notepad++="C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe"'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Escape them. Use this instead:

```
echo "alias notepad++="C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: it works for me. thx